# Renaming button name

Tags: java

I need to change the default name of button, checkbox etc in java but didn't find property to do this.
I am able to change the text, but not the button, checkbox name which are often refereed in code.

Could somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by button name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but the String name is a java.awt.Component property.

In case you mean this name,
you can change a component's name with [`.setName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) and get the name with [`.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29).

A component's name by default is null, until you set it. It makes usually sense to `.getName()` in listeners.

Here is an example. If you have many panels, you can set each name:

```
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.addMouseListener((MouseListener) this);
        p.setName("Panel" + i + "_" + j);
```

and then check in order to find where your mouse was clicked at:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {            
        JPanel p = (JPanel) e.getSource();
        String s = p.getName();
        String[] numbers = s.replaceAll("^\\D+", "").split("\\D+");
        int y = Integer.valueOf(numbers[0]);
        int x = Integer.valueOf(numbers[1]);
        ...
```

Comment: this is what i need. when I added a checkbox, default name is jChechBox1. in my coding i use if (jChechBox1 = selected){} . issue here is this name doesn't have any meaning. I am thinking like csharp. i am writing small utility in java though I have never done programming in java. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text of a button when it was already created, you can simply do

```
MyButton.setText("new Text");
```

Comment: his is what i need. when I added a checkbox, default name is jChechBox1. in my coding i use if (jChechBox1 = selected){} . issue here is this name doesn't have any meaning. I am thinking like csharp. i am writing small utility in java though I have never done programming in java. Thanks..